# Can't run Django project

Tags: python, django

I wanted to run official Django tutorial. I've installed Django using pip, and started the project. And when I run `python manage.py runserver` the console shows the same thing as in tutorial, but when I open the page `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` or `localhost:8000` I only see `404 not found`.

Comment: can you check the port number that you are using same after running the server?

Comment: what's on the terminal?

Comment: Are you sure http://127.0.0.1:8000/ is the right URL to go to instead of http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin or http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls?

Comment: Set DEBUG = True in your settings file so that you get better error pages while you are developing. It would have provided you with a good error page that would have said that it can't find a url pattern.

Comment: Thank you guys, for helping me. I just reinstalled everything and it just works.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the `404` error because in your `urls.py` you have not added url for `/`.

Try in your browser: `localhost:8000/admin` and it should work.